# ¿Alguien sabe cómo pasar los valores de un DateChooser a una columna de una JTable?

Tags: java, jcalendar

```
private void Datos_Personales_BTN_GuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String datos [] = new String [16];
        datos [0] = Datos_Personales_TXT_Id.getText();
        datos [1] = Datos_Personales_TXT_Nombre.getText();
        datos [2] = Datos_Personales_TXT_Apellido_Paterno.getText();
        datos [3] = Datos_Personales_TXT_Apellido_Materno.getText();
        datos [4] = Datos_Personales_TXT_Correo_Institucional.getText();
        datos [5] = Datos_Personales_TXT_Matricula.getText();
        datos [6] = this.Datos_Personales_CMB_Sexo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        datos [7] = this.Datos_Personales_CMB_Edad.getSelectedItem().toString();
        datos [8] = this.Datos_Personales_CMB_Cargo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        datos [9] = this.Datos_Personales_CMB_Departamento.getSelectedItem().toString();
        datos [10] = this.Datos_Personales_JCalendar_Fecha_Nac.getDateFormatString().toString();
        datos [11] = Datos_Personales_TXT_Curp.getText();
        datos [12] = Datos_Personales_TXT_Telefono.getText();
        datos [13] = Datos_Personales_TXT_RFC.getText();
        datos [14] = Datos_Personales_CMB_Tipo_Sangre.getSelectedItem().toString();
        datos [15] = Datos_Personales_JCalendar_Fecha.getDateFormatString().toString();
        Datos_Personales.addRow(datos);
    }
```

Comment: Tu Date chooser es el cmponente de la librería JCalendar?

Comment: Si, estoy utilizando el JCalendar.jar para insertar el calendario como campo de texto, solo que me hace falta hacer que la fecha insertada pase a la JTable como registro

Comment: puees poner el códdigo de `Datos_Personales` para estar seguro que no es una clase?

Answer (score 1):

Yo coloco la fecha de un DateChooser en un JTable de esta forma

```
String dia = Integer.toString(date_nacimiento.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
String mes = Integer.toString(date_nacimiento.getCalendar().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
String year = Integer.toString(date_nacimiento.getCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR));
Datos[10] = (year + "/" + mes+ "/" + dia);
```